# Facebook API : How to redirect the page after clicking "Login with facebook" using XFBML (Login Button)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to let Facebook Login button redirect to a particular URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200167/how-to-let-facebook-login-button-redirect-to-a-particular-url)

I am using the Facebook's login button (XFBML) to login users.. to my app..

But as one clicks the button.. its logs you in but remains on the same page.. how to redirect it.. to home page ?

here is the snippet :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=APP_ID&amp;xfbml=1">
</script>
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
```

So.. what to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

```
<script>
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        alert("Logged in.. Redirecting you now...");
        // window.location = "some other page";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Well.. I worked out a way.. thanks for the answer.. !