# Facebook simple login

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to let Facebook Login button redirect to a particular URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200167/how-to-let-facebook-login-button-redirect-to-a-particular-url)

I have this code. It properly connects to facebook. But the problem is how can I redirect it to the home page ?

```
<head>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=32292*******";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="50" data-max-rows="2"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: the facebook-js SDK should be placed **under** the `<body>` tag not in the `<head>`!!!

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
window.location="http://www.facebook.com";
```

I type `facebook` as example, but you can set any `URL` you want to redirect to.