# Facebook like button on Apache Cordova/Phonegap app

Tags: facebook, cordova, button, facebook-like

I have inserted a facebook like button with this methods like a simple web:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

But the first time that a button is pressed a login window opens. This window opens in the current window, not in a new window. After the user logs in the window try to close itself but it can't. A white window is showed.
Next times the like button works correctly because the user is logged in.

I also try to implement with the cordova plugin "phonegap-facebook-plugin" but it doesn't have support for like button.
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Comment: i am also facing the same problem. Did any one find the solution?

Comment: I've provided a solution here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27839838/1282237 - does this help?

Comment: Better you try this - https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#how-do-i-add-a-like-button

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to listen to when they've finished logging in and redirect back to you're application some like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5638337/2481696).

Only with `window.location` set to something like `file:///android_asset/www/index.html` or whatever page you want to return the user to.

`<fb:login-button onlogin="document.location.href='file:///android_asset/www/index.html';">
</fb:login-button>`

Something like this but for the like button ?

Comment: I tried it but doesn't work. After login other blank window is loaded. This window try execute "window.close()" but is not a new window...is the main window.

Comment: When I open the app second time means first time I just logged in and blank page came, like button is working but i am not getting callback on it.