# Facebook Like button + Phonegap

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-like, phonegap-build

I'm trying to use Facebook Like button in my Phonegap (HTML + JS) app, but it doesn't work.

If I test it in the browser (local test), the button appears.

But when I build it with Phonegap BUild and run it in my smartphone, the button is not showed.

I'm using the code below:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Save-Points/293951217439051" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Comment: I will not, unless facebook app WEBSITE URL is same as your application URL.

Comment: @jeekonline That shouldn't be an issue, with local testing I had a different URL yet the FB like button still appeared. Also this question is similar to an existing question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871644/facebook-like-button-on-apahe-cordova-phonegap-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current way to implement the like action is by using the open graph object `og.like` - FB's documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes?locale=en_GB). It's important to note that this method requires the `publish_actions` permission from the user. It's a bit of work to get this all running smoothly, but it is possible.

The [phonegap-facebook-plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) has provided a guide [here](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/develop/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#how-do-i-add-a-like-button). Below are the instructions with some of my comments:

> - Your like button must not be the same (graphically) as the Facebook like button

This means no "thumbs up" symbol - quite a frustration!

> - When you display your page / button you have to call the getLoginStatus method first to know if the current user is connected to its Facebook account. If he is connected then call GET https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes?access_token=FB_ACCESS_TOKEN&object=URL_TO_LIKE with the Facebook Access Token returned by the g3. etAccessToken method (if this returns data then style your like button with a red heart for example, a grey heart if the call returns an empty array).

Along with checking a user is logged in, to reiterate you must check your app has `publish_actions` permission for the user. Though you could possibly request this upon the Like action.

Also, the array is in the `data` property of the response object. If you're checking as to whether the user has liked this URL, you'll basically want to check `response.data.length > 0`.

> - To create a like (when your user clicks on your like button and your like button is a grey heart) do a POST on https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes?access_token=FB_ACCESS_TOKEN&object=URL_TO_LIKE NOTE: You must have publish_actions permission to do this

After doing this, the URL has been successfully liked by the user, and now the `GET` method will return an array with one object. Calling this when the user already has liked the URL will result in an error.

> - To remove a like (when your user clicks on your like button and your like button is a red heart) do a DELETE on https://graph.facebook.com/LIKE_IDENTIFIER?access_token=FB_ACCESS_TOKEN. The LIKE_IDENTIFIER is returned from steps 2 or 3.

The unlike (`DELETE`) method is different to the rest - it's not based off `/me`, and instead of filtering via URL, you use the like id. You'll likely have to call the previously described `GET` method to get the ID (do `response.data[0].id`).